# Firebase SignedURL not equal to download url Storage

Tags: android, url, firebase, download, firebase-storage

I've asked a question previously to get the downloadURL from Firebase Storage, the answer that was given to me was:

```
bucket.file(filename).getSignedUrl({
  action: 'read',
  expires: '03-17-2025'
}, function(err, url) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }

  // The file is now available to read from this URL.
  request(url, function(err, resp) {
    // resp.statusCode = 200
  });
});
```

The one given to be by the previous code doesn´t work when I use it to download an image using Glide or reporducing an audio or video file using ExoPlayer.

However I get a completely different URL than the one that is given by the Firebase Storage, (which does work for Glide and ExoPlayer) when a file is upload which looks like this:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project-PROYECT_NUMBER.appspot.com/o/Messages%2Fimages%2F-KUj4wvXXl6aj9XXXX%2F1493147111111?alt=media&token=TOKEN

How can I get the proper downloadUrl like the one I would get using the Android or the iOS SDK, on the server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to get the download url on server side like you can when using the Android, iOS or Javascript SDK. You have to generate a url by calling getSignedUrl().

You might want to check if you have permission to read the file at the given URL.

By default you have to be authenticated.

Check your storage rules in the firebase console

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/#authorization

Answer (score 1):

I hope your uploading the image through app only na ? Once its uploaded you will get back the download link. I hope this will hep you out.

```
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask;

 final StorageTask uploadTask = uplodedFileRef.putBytes(data);
    Log.d(TAG, "uploadFilefromPath: " + uplodedFileRef.getPath().toString());
uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                    Toast.makeText(acty, "Upload Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    sendResult(false, Uri.EMPTY);
                }
            })
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                    Toast.makeText(acty, "Upload Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    sendResult(true, taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl());
                }
            })
            .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    int bytesTransferred = (int) taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred();
                    int totalBytes = (int) taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                    int progress = (100 * bytesTransferred) / totalBytes;

                    Log.v(TAG, "Bytes transferred: " + taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred());
                    Log.v(TAG, "TotalBytes: " + totalBytes);
                    Log.v(TAG, "Upload is: " + progress + "% done");

                    dialog.setContent("Upload in Progress");
                    dialog.getProgressBar().setIndeterminate(false);
                    // double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                    dialog.getProgressBar().setMax(totalBytes / 1024);
                    dialog.setMaxProgress(totalBytes / 1024);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                        dialog.getProgressBar().setProgress(bytesTransferred / 1024, true);
                        dialog.setProgress(bytesTransferred / 1024);
                    } else
                        dialog.getProgressBar().setProgress(bytesTransferred / 1024);
                    dialog.setProgress(bytesTransferred / 1024);
                    // dialog.getProgressBar().setProgress((int) progress);
                }
            });
```

Comment: the problem is that I m doing that I want to retrieve that URL via the server

Comment: see i have added answer  look into it @Andrea

Comment: I´m sorry but the answer don´t correspond to what I´m asking for, I need to retrieve that URL in the Firebase Functions node code

Comment: First you should mention in the question clearly na?

Answer (score 1):

```
addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) { //success
            sendResult(true, taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl());
      }
})
```

in this `taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl()` you will receive the download url then you save it in firebase database  you can able to retrieve as an when

Comment: I´m sorry but the answer don´t correspond to what I´m asking for, I need to retrieve that URL in the Firebase Functions node code

Comment: Using above method you should store download URL in a node and then access that node from your Firebase functions.